# Spreadsheetgear: Exporting from DataGrid and DataList to single Excel file plus formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, spreadsheetgear

Previously before installing `SpreadSheetGear`, I manage to have an export button that can export all the correct data from both the `DataList` and `DataGrid` into an Excel file, but the formatting is a big problem. After every row of data from the `DataList`, there will be another blank row. I need to bold the texts in a few cells and create borders, and currently there is no row to separate the `DataList` and `DataGrid`, they are joint together.

How do I go about using `SpreadSheetGear` to export the `DataList` and `DataGrid` to a single Excel file?

Or are there other libraries that can do this more efficiently?

Edit: On SpreadSheetGear website, there are samples and How-To sections, but the closest I can find is from Excel to DataGrid, totally different from what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example for conversion of a DataTable to an Excel sheet can help:

http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/asp.net.sample.aspx?sample=insertdatatabletoworkbook

Comment: Thanks, that does help. But I realise that there is only `CopyFromDataTable` and there is no option for `DataList` and `DataGrid`. Does that means I have to convert these two into DataTables? As they originate from an `ArrayList` which is derived from a `DataTable` themselves, from a `Collections` class.

Comment: I found some code to get from Excel to a DataTable to a list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168548/populate-mvc-webgrid-from-datatable but I have't tried to go back the other way